# how to check if file is available in internal storage

Tags: android, download

I am trying to download a file from the internet and it succeeded but now
I want to check if the file exists in the internal storage.

```
else if (arg0.getId() == R.id.btn_download)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "download button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(names[b]));
    request.setDescription("Downloading..");
    request.setTitle("Futsing Magazine Issue " + (this.mPictureManager.getCurrentIndex() +1) );
    // in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    }
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Futsing Magazine Issue " + (this.mPictureManager.getCurrentIndex()
            +1) +".pdf");

    // get download service and enqueue file
    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);
```

The items retrieved are downloaded to /mnt/sdcard/Download.
How do I check if the file exists or not using code?

Comment: use exists() method of File class to check it.

Comment: Please note this is not Internal storage since DownloadManager cannot access Internal Storage for any application. It's package-specific External Storage. Refer to: `https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's say following is your file's path

```
String path=context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/filename";
File file = new File ( path ); 

if ( file.exists() ) 
{
     // Toast File is exists
}
else
{
     // Toast File is not exists
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
File applictionFile =  new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+ "/"+<file-name>);

    if(applictionFile != null && applictionFile.exists()){

   }
```

if file is getting downloads in to default donwload directory